# Can I delete second Ubuntu's files?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, uninstall, 16.10

I have to `Ubuntu` versions on different partitions.

One (`12.04`) older and have the bigger partition with very important files. Also, it has so many files, that I can't just copy them into the second partition to `16.10`. But I have some problems with `12.04` version and want to delete it and keep all my files.

Can I just delete all files except `/home/<user>` directory and be happy?

**update**:

I have deleted all system files from thet bigger partition but now partition called `DELLUTILITY` (because I'm working with Dell laptop) and `OS` partition are inside it and laptop still asks me what I need to boot.

Comment: Theoretically yes, provided you can access the 12.04's /home when running 16.10 and, of course, /home is a different partition, i.e., not inside /.

Comment: The better approach is to get a large enough external media, backup and then manage partitions.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I don't have any large external media. I need ~900Gb

Comment: What files, exactly, do you want to keep ? Is it your user files, so Documents, Videos, Pictures etc ?

Comment: First just rename the directories to see if it works without them. Then, when you are sure it works, delete them.

Comment: @hatterman Yes, it is just a lot of video, some documents.
@nobody Do you mean rename system folders in `12.04`'s partition and test if `16.04` still work well?

Comment: When you installed 16.10, did you also install grub ? If you did, then you will be just fine deleting anything you don't want on the 12.04 partition. If you didn't install grub, then you will need to keep the /boot folder on the 12.04 partition. This, off course, is assumng you are using BIOS and not EUFI. Like 'nobody' says, rename the /boot folder in the 12.04 partition and see if you still boot. (You will need a live CD to hand in case you can't boot and need to rename it back).

Comment: For what it is worth, I always have one large partition with my data in it and then have multiple smaller partitions for OS's. I then create links in my /home folder (of each OS) to folders in my large partition.  This way, I can delete OS's at will, re-format partitions, install and uninstall different distros and I will always have my important data.

Comment: @hatterman I didn't manually install `grub`, and have mounted the new partition for `16.04` to `/` and manually added `boot` flag to it. PC asks me what OS I want to boot.

Comment: If the PC asks you, then I guess you are using UEFI ? You'll probably have a UEFI boot partition in this case. However, I am not a UEFI expert, in fact I have so far chosen to stay well clear of it. I am happy with BIOS. I will gracefully back out at this stage as I don't want to bork your system!

Comment: May be best to see details, you can run from Ubuntu live installer or any working install:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info
  Grub does not use Boot flag to know what to boot. Windows does, syslinux does, and UEFI does on ESP - efi system partition.